# How do I solve an error in pgadmin4: syntax error at or near "REPLACE"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to pgadmin4, and this is a very simple problem. I have a table called lc_2020 like this, and I want to REPLACE a row, which is equal to delete+insert operations. The row I want to replace is the first row.
[image]

I enter this in pgAdmin4 - query editor but got errors. I wonder if my syntax DOES have errors or it's pgadmin4 requiring a different format for REPLACE.

```
REPLACE into lc_2020 (quad_id, task_type, cur_prep_num)
values ('001001', '88', 66);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REPLACE"
LINE 1: REPLACE into lc_2020 (quad_id, task_type, cur_prep_num) ;
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) did you find that `REPLACE` is a valid SQL command? If you want to change an existing row, then just UPDATE it.

Comment: There is no `REPLACE` in Postgresql. What you want is `UPDATE`. FYI,  without a `WHERE` this will update all the rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539838/replace-versus-insert-in-sql But I was specifically asked to do a delete+insert operation, which is REPLACE, according to this post. I canNOT use update. Do I have to do a delete then insert instead? Thanks for replying to me!

Comment: In Postgresql an update is a delete\insert.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the explanation. I am looking into that.

Comment: @ClaireWang. Postgres has a `REPLACE` function which works with text (strings). But as has been indicated it does not have a REPLACE DML operation. The link you posted refers to MySQL not Postgres..

Comment: A _real_ delete/insert would cause a lot of problems with foreign keys referencing the row to be "deleted". An UPDATE is almost always a better alternative, especially if you don't change all columns

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name I change all columns and I don't think I have a foreign key. Thanks!

Comment: So the query would be `UPDATE lc_2020 SET (task_type, cur_prep_num) = ('88', 66) WHERE quad_id = '001001';`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Adrian Klaver and @a_horse_with_no_name 's answers.

Depending on your own request, the code should be:
(numbers are made up)

```
delete from lc_2020 where quad_id = '001002';
insert into lc_2020 (quad_id, task_type, cur_prep_num) values ('001002', '77', 66);
```

OR

```
update lc_2020 set task_type = '78', cur_prep_num = 43
where quad_id = '001002'
```

Comment: FYI, Postgres also supports 'UPSERT' via the [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause to `INSERT`. This will `UPDATE` an existing record if the `INSERT` unique constraint matches, otherwise it will insert  the record.